# getting comments on facebook is limited to 50?

Tags: facebook

strangely , lately when I'm trying to retrieve comments with the old facebook api I can get only the latest 50. 
And I didnt see any paging option there.
And it doesnt matter if I use stream.getcomments or directly FQL .
 The weird thing is that using the same fql with the new api gives me all the comments.
got a clue?

Comment: I guess the solution there is to use the new API then? I don't understand the question.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to avoid that. it will be time consuming for me to convert everything to the new API including the authorization and all the functions.

Comment: While it may be a PITA to convert to the new API shouldn't you start doing it. Have they said how long the old API will be around? The next step after depreciating an API is to retire it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the offset parameter in your requests to return the next page of comments

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this question. as much as I remember I tried this (anyhow, if the fql itself, which shouldnt be "paged" is blocking me form getting more than 50, it's not likely that the "wrapped" methods that are based on fql would bring me more) anyway, I converted to the new API , at least partially.